# Есть ли решение border-radius в IE 7-8?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Есть решение, которое сделало чтобы IE 7-8 вело себя как нормальный браузер?
`border.htc` и `curved-corner`, `css pie` - не то, сразу говорю.

Answer (score 1):

посмотрите http://ru.html5boilerplate.com/

Но я бы не советовал лепить на старые браузеры новые плюшки. Считаю, что достаточно сделать адекватное отображение содержимого в этих браузурах и все.

Comment: Farrock, клиенты кка правило одним местом смотрят на то что мы себе считаем.

Comment: До этих клиентов в таком случае доносится информация о повышении бюджета разработки.

Например для верстки под IE 6 цена увеличивается иногда в разы

Comment: Ну в разы, это вы загнули, с версткой там проблем нет (вернее многие баги давно известны и легко решаются даже при помощи гугла), а вот если придираются, что яваскрипт медленно и не так работает, вот это уже в разы.

Comment: (IMHO) Как раз все наоборот. Поддерживать устаревшую технологию спецкостылями — та еще черная магия и стоит отдельных денег. Писать качественный код — прямая обязанность каждого, для чего иначе нанимают-то? Понятно, что у хорошего кодера ценовая вилка будет выше, чем у мастера индусского стиля… Но когда один и тот же человек хочет дополнительных денег за то, чтобы скрипт «не тормозил» — это явный признак или плохо поставленного ТЗ (т.е., скажем, заказчик говорил о паре эффектных кнопочек, а в итоге пришлось увешать ими весь сайт как новогоднюю елку) или того, что в консерватории что-то не так

Comment: Парни Google отказался от поддержки ie6 и от 7 тоже собирается отказаться,так что можно клиентов огорчить)
А Я вопрос поднял потому что ie7 пока живет,и многие не умеют обновлять браузеры(OMG)

Answer (score 0):

1. Выучить VRML/CSV
2. [Создать при помощи картинок](http://www.artlebedev.ru/tools/technogrette/html/rounded-corners/)

CSS3 эти два браузера не понимают.

Comment: Получается чтобы в IE 7-8 были скругленные углы надо картинками все сделать,если не устраивает csspie и.т.д ?

Comment: Да, совершенно верно. Либо использовать векторную графику. Но это весьма сложно для данной цели.

Comment: "Векторная графика" прочитаю обязательно,не слышал никогда)
Все таки сделаю изображениями,IE позволяет

Answer (score 0):

А вот [тут](http://fetchak.com/ie-css3/) ребята говорят что всё таки можно сделать кроссбраузерный border-radius
(в IE 8 работает)